# Pass object from GridView of Fragment to ListView of another Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-gridview

I have a GridView in FragmentA containing all objects. When the user tap on each object, these objects are added into ListView of FragmentB.

Note that FragmentA and FragmentB are both in the same Activity, side by side.

I have tried using Bundle to send object from FragmentA to FragmentB but I was stucked as I have no idea how FragmentB is going to know that a new object has been added.

Bundle object is sent from ProductGridAdapter (under FragmentA) and receiver will be FragmentB where FragmentB will update the ListView for the latest objects added by FragmentA

Here is my code:

ProductGridAdapter.java

```
public class ProductGridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    private List<Product> productList;
    private Context context;

    public ProductGridAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                          List<Product> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.productList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != productList) ?
                productList.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Product getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != productList) ?
                productList.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(null == view) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_product, null);
        }

        final Product product = productList.get(position);

        if(product != null) {
            final CardView productGridLayout = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_gridlayout);
            final TextView productName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            final ImageView productIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_icon);

            productName.setText(product.getName());
            productIcon.setImageDrawable(product.getDrawable());

            productGridLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("product", product);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                }
            });
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    private ProductGridAdapter productAdapter;

    public FragmentA() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_display, container, false);

        gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        productAdapter = new ProductGridAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_product_display, getProductList());
        gridView.setAdapter(productAdapter);

        gridView.destroyDrawingCache();
        gridView.setVisibility(GridView.INVISIBLE);
        gridView.setVisibility(GridView.VISIBLE);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

FragmentB.java

```
 public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

        private ListView listView;
        private PaymentListAdapter paymentAdapter;
        private LinearLayout button;
        private ArrayList<String> arr;

        public FragmentB() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payment, container, false);

            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            paymentAdapter = new PaymentListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_payment, getProductList());
            //  button = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.payment);

            listView.setAdapter(paymentAdapter);

            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            Product product = (Product) bundle.getSerializable("product");

            return rootView;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have two common method in interface class in main activity, To update view in both fragment,When some changes happens in FragmentA you have to notify that changes to main activity then main activity should communicate to FragementB about that changes.try to do as like this,Hope this will help you.Happy Coding!